# Why is $\varphi\colon A^G\to A$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $G$ be a group and $e_G$ its neutral element. Moreover, let $A$ be a finite set. $A$ is equipped with the discrete toplogy, $A^G$ with the product topology.
Let $\tau\colon A^G\to A^G$ be continuous and define $\varphi\colon A^G\to A, \varphi(x):=\tau(x)(e_G)$.

It is said that $\varphi$ is continuous.

What is the reason for that?

Has that something to do with the assumed continuity of $\tau$?

Comment: The product topology on $A^G$ is the least topology such that all projections $A^G\to A$ (evaluation of a function in $A^G$ at some fixed element) are continuous.

Comment: So I do not need the continuity of $\tau$?

Comment: No, you definitely need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We think to $A^G$ as the set of maps $G\to A$. The product topology is the least topology such that all maps $\varepsilon_x\colon A^G\to A$ defined by 
$$
\varepsilon_x(f)=f(x)
$$
(for $x\in G$) are continuous. Then $\varphi=\varepsilon_{e_G}\circ \tau$ is continuous as composition of continuous functions.

Comment: @math12 Note that, at this level, the fact that $G$ is a group is irrelevant; instead of $e^{}_G$ you could use any element of $G$.